# Determine actual Linq2SQL execution time

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to audit the performance of our application while it is running. We have a built in audit mechanism that works like this.

db.startAudit(); and db.endAudit();

Each is called when a DB query starts and ends. This gives us great performance metrics without any performance hit. This enables great production metrics.

However, Linq2SQL is deferred execution with IQueryable.

How can I link in my db.startAudit and db.endAudit with linq2SQL so that I can tracked the deferred execution? We use c# and sql server 2012

Thanks,
/Z

Comment: can you run any execution plans or performance counters what have you done in regards to researching Performance software or metrics..?

Comment: Try to call db.startAudit()/endAudit at the instant of actual execution the queries,e.g, before /after query.Tolist() or foreach{.....}. Use sql profiler to review the sent linq2sql statements and the auditing.